# what's wrong with this python line?

Tags: python

The following line in my source code:

```
a = testSourceDir.find("\\", testSourceDir.find("\\drv")+1)
```

is in the shell displayed as:

```
a = testSourceDir.find("\", testSourceDir.find("\\drv")+1)
```

but gives the following error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "is in the shell displayed as". Are you saving this in a .py file, or running it it a python console.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the `\`:

```
a= testSourceDir.find("\\", testSourceDir.find("\\drv")+1)
```

More about escape sequences [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: this is what I had written as you can see

Comment: Something is not right with this code. In the `find` function, you are calling `find` again?

Answer (score 3):

"is in the shell displayed as:"

What do you mean with that?

The first line is correct. The second line is not. What's wrong with it is that you have only one backslash, so instead of `'\\'`, ie a string containing only a backslash which is what you intend to write, the first string is in fact `'\", testSourceDir.find('`. That string doesn't start with a backslash, it starts with a double quote, and ends with a (.

So that's what is wrong. The strange thing here is your statement "is in the shell displayed as". No it's not. I don't know what you are doing but in general a backslash is "displayed" as `\\`.